# Lookup filter Question -- Tricky One (Lightning)

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Its a tricky situation fail to get it. i am a newbie in SF. Here is the scenario --

There is a lookup filter on Product Interest field &
Product Brand is a PickList

what's happening is that out of 6 picklist values for Product Brands only one is causing Lookup functionality to fail i.e Products corresponding to that particular brand do'not show up in Product Interest field.
-Show All does nothing,
-Typing related values (from Workbench) does nothing,
-Adding a new product does not register new product with that particular brand.
-tried comparing WorkBench data with other brands no conclusion still

Any clues y'all might be able to provide. Thank you so much in advance.

Regards,
Sunny

Answer (score 1):

Some screenshots would help to understand your issue...

**Data visibility**

Are you sysadmin? If not - maybe there are matching rows but sharing rules prevent you from seeing it. Does it show the records in the lookup OK when you change the filter from mandatory to optional?

**Data quality**

Are you sure there are no typos, that the brand picklist on the record you're creating / modifying is identical to the brand picklist (or whatever it is) on product? Don't look at the label (what's shown in the UI), look at picklist value (what's actually stored in the database). Labels can be translated to other languages but filters and custom code compare values.

**Other debugging ideas**

Is it a standard create/edit screen or a custom component? If needed - would you know how to run the standard create screen and/or go to Classic UI?

Can you import a record bypassing the UI. Ask admin how to use Data Import Wizard, Data Loader or maybe programmer could help you with piece of code to run in developer console. Something like

```
MyObject__c o = new MyObject__c(
    ProductBrand__c = 'Problematic',
    ProductInterest__c = '01t....' // the Id of product you hope to see in the lookup that has same "Problematic" picklist value
);
insert o;
System.debug(o.Id);
```

Maybe it'll work, maybe it'll throw you an error that will help investigating.

Do you have record types on the object, maybe the problematic picklist value is not legal for the record type you're using and you'd need to allow it first.

Can you reverse the create action. Like go to Product layout editor, add a related list of "MyObjects" (or whatever it is you're inserting) and try to create using the "New" button on the related list. Hopefully that should come with the product preselected in the lookup or show you some error.